# aws s3 configuration syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am trying to use aws s3 with heroku and the paperclip gem.
While running `git push heroku master`, I keep getting this syntax error (I have hidden the access keys)

```
# Command Line
remote: SyntaxError: /tmp/build_f1b59509e4d703e2f559ca42123c2f30/config/environments/production.rb:84: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting '}'
remote: :access_key_id = ENV['access_key'],
remote: ^
remote: /tmp/build_f1b59509e4d703e2f559ca42123c2f30/config/environments/production.rb:85: syntax error, unexpected '=>', expecting :: or '[' or '.'
remote: :secret_access_key = ENV['secret_key']
remote: ^
remote: /tmp/build_f1b59509e4d703e2f559ca42123c2f30/config/environments/production.rb:86: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
```

Heroku devcenter instructed me to use this code shown below.https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

```
    # config/environments/production.rb
    config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
        :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
        :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      }
    }
```

I've tried changing syntax but I can't get anywhere. If you have any other recommendations on how to save paperclip gem images to an s3 bucket please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Have you set your ENV in your Heroku application ?

Comment: Yes it is set to production

Comment: Have you try without ENV ?

Comment: What would that code look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the master branch of Paperclip, you should be using the was gem above 2.0.0 and you may need to make a couple changes in order to get it to work. From the paperclip documentation:

> Paperclip is now compatible with aws-sdk >= 2.0.0.
>
> If you are using S3 storage, aws-sdk >= 2.0.0 requires you to make a few ?>small
>   changes:
>
> - You must set the `s3_region`
> - If you are explicitly setting permissions anywhere, such as in an >initializer,
>     note that the format of the permissions changed from using an underscore >to
>     using a hyphen. For example, `:public_read` needs to be changed to
>     `public-read`.

In one of my projects, I had started with an earlier branch and then upgraded and got the same error you got when pushing to heroku. I updated the credentials to include the region and that fixed the problem for me.